# LeftNavBar bleeds into list view

Tags: android, google-tv

I am using the LeftNavBar for a Google TV app. For some reason, it bleeds into the content area on the right. Here's a piece from the screenshot - it's a little hard to see, but the tab separators on the left are bleeding into the content on the right - it's most obvious on the white icons since the separators are dark. The screenshot is from a Sony Google TV. I see something slightly different on a Logitech Revue because the LeftNavBar has a background and a separator on the right, but there too the content still bleeds into the right side (I don't know why the appearance of LeftNavBar differs between the Sony and the Logitech). Unfortunately, I couldn't take a snapshot of my the Logitech - DDMS gives me a generic error when I try.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong to cause this?

I also wasn't able to find a place to ask questions or log bugs against LeftNavBar - the  [project page](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/) is very sparse:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try changing res/lib_leftnav_bar_dimens.xml to and it should fix it for you:

```
<resources>  
    <dimen name="left_nav_collapsed_width">62dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="left_nav_collapsed_apparent_width">50dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="left_nav_expanded_width">182dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="left_nav_expanded_apparent_width">182dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="left_nav_icon_size">36dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="title_bar_height">52dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="title_bar_apparent_height">52dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

As Les mentioned earlier, it doesn't seem like a universal fix, so I will update the library once I find the best fix.

Comment: Thanks. Technically, this is just as correct as the other answer. I'm sticking with the padding suggestion for the moment, but it appears either would work well.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an update to it next week to fix this.  It's a known bug.  You might wish to add some margin to your view to take care of this.

I talked with one of my colleague's who told me that you should change the source as it really depends on the length of your items.  Perhaps she'll comment here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The padding worked fine, so I'll stick with that until I see a fix. Both yours and Megha Joshi's are correct and useful answers - much appreciated!